# MySQL WorkBench devs can't change password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create users for MySQL with the option for them to change the password:

[image]

But when Devs connect on Workbench, they receive a message:

```
Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

I tried to find the answer but with no success.

How can I use this option and make devs be able to change their passwords on Workbench? Or do they need to log on Linux ?

Comment: What is the version of MySQL Workbench they use ?

Comment: It's 5.2.47 CW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an updated version of MySQL Workbench, the latest version currently is 8.0.26

If it doesn't work, they will probably have to use a more "basic" tool like a shell "mysql".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expired-password-handling.html

You may also have to check what the disconnect-on-expired-password parameter is at :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_disconnect_on_expired_password

Comment: I just discovered that they are using (at least this one guy) a workbench/J build 127 / java version 1.8.0. I've never heard of it. Thaks for the help I will test it with myself ( since I'm using the real workbench)

Comment: @RacerSQL MySQL Workbench is written in C++. I have no idea what your user is using. Maybe some totally different GUI client product?